# Rolling back an edit of a "Thanks" answer that was flagged NAA

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

There was [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524654/5781745) that was saying "Thanks" to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46335203/5781745) and basically just copied-pasted the code from that other answer.

[While in the LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21542784), a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685938/david) edited out the "Thanks" portion, making the edited version of this answer *appear* to be a *code-only answer* (to which the LQP queue will no longer have the context of why it was placed there to begin with).

Is the appropriate recourse to this edit to **roll-back** to the previous version in order to provide the LQP review queue context as to why it was flagged NAA to begin with? Otherwise, future reviewers may not see this and mark the post as "Looks Okay".

As of writing this post, here's the results so far of the review:

```
david reviewed this 11 mins ago: Edit
scopchanov reviewed this 25 mins ago: Recommend Deletion
K.Dᴀᴠɪs reviewed this 1 hour ago: Recommend Deletion
Mozahler reviewed this 3 hours ago: Recommend Deletion
```

Comment: There should definitely be a comment on the question pointing out that it is just a copy/paste is another answer. 5 bucks says the editor didn't realize that was the case. I don't know what a rollback would do to existing votes/flags on the answer though.

Comment: If the bad edit is not rolled back previously (no rollback war yet), just rollback first next time.

Comment: I really didn't see it coming. I only look at that answer and try to fix it. That's all. Even if my review is not helpful, I don't see why I got review ban this time. This is so sudden.

Comment: @david the temporary review ban is just to alert you to the situation. Next time review more carefully and don't edit posts that are not answers. I've lifted the ban now since you responded.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @SamuelLiew. I will appreciate it and try to review things more carefully.

Comment: There is no "so far" for this review. Editing a post from review (using the blue "Edit" button) removes the post from the review queue. That's it. The review is done. The post would have had to be re-flagged/voted on again for it to re-enter the queue.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after I posted. That’s generally why I edit possible temptations out of the post that I intend to flag before I flag it, because there’s always that someone who wants to edit a code block or capitalize that ‘i’, @Makyen

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I know how you feel. I'll often do a quick edit, particularly on posts I've close-voted (edits from those who voted to close don't put the question in the reopen queue), to perform the edits commonly done by drive-by editors (e.g. code formatting, inline images, etc.), just to make it less likely that someone will kick it out of the queue by editing (or for closed questions, put it in the reopen queue).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is the appropriate recourse to this edit to **roll-back** to the previous version in order to provide the LQP review queue context as to why it was flagged NAA to begin with? Otherwise, future reviewers may not see this and mark the post as "Looks Okay".

Yes, this is absolutely the right way to go. That edit completely changed the nature of the answer, but all it ends up doing is changing it to make it look like it was stolen from the other answer. Even moderators have trouble spotting these types of thank-you answers and miscategorizing them as plagiarism as it is — let's not make it any harder for everyone.

If the answer should be edited by a third party at all, it should be edited to make it clearer that this was intended to be a thank-you answer. How one might go about such an edit is left as an exercise to the reader. Of course, the best approach to this is to leave a comment stating the nature of the answer rather than trying to edit it.

Comment: *"How one might go about such an edit is left as an exercise to the reader."* - perhaps by editing from "{{content of the other answer}}. Thanks!" to something more like: "Hey, @otheranswerer, your [other answer on this same question](link) with this content: <blockquote>{{content of the other answer}}</blockquote> was great, thanks!"? Still, commenting to point out what's going on seems like it's probably the less confusing & drama-inviting approach. I foresee being on the receiving end of a lot of rollbacks and mod flags if I start editing posts to make them *more obviously* rule-violating.

Comment: I prefer people to not edit these answers, but not because some vague "changing intentions", but because is a waste of resources given that it doesn't make the answer objectively better.

Comment: @Mark Amery: Yeah, the "If the answer should be edited by a third party at all" portion is meant to suggest that editing probably isn't the best idea. I'll add the comment recommendation to my answer.

Comment: The only problem is that comments don't seem to work. In the example provided above, two very obvious comments showing why the post should be deleted went ignored and the question was still edited to remove the offending criteria anyway.

Answer (score -20):

This constitutes an abuse of the "Edit" function of the review.

It only supposed to be used if the editor is able to fix the problem(s) that caused the post to be flagged. That's why an "edit" vote terminates the review.

Flag this for moderator attention and let them take it from here.

---

**DO NOT** roll back an edit if it improved the post. If the post is still delete-worthy, whether for the same or another reason, explain this to the moderator in your flag message and/or flag the post as NAA again if you can.

Comment: "DO NOT roll back an edit if it improved the post." It didn't though. It changed it from a "thanks" answer to an unintentionally plagiarized answer. If anything, it made it worse.